# trouble in fetching object from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios

i am making dictionary with 2 array one for keys(ids that you can see in Dic) and one for values(Birth dates that you can see in Dic) my dictionary look like this

```
100000297621293 = "08/31/1990";
100001904155266 = "12/30/1990";
100003248631105 = "05/27/1990";
100004327360299 = "01/01/1927";
100000157646688 = "08/22/1989";
100001069796883 = "12/03/1989";
100001475514001 = "03/09/1990";
100000717474427 = "08/05/1990";
100001221367192 = "08/05/1990";
100002586744158 = "04/15/1983";
```

this is just sample dic not full

then after i have another array with ids and im using that array for fetching birth dates from this Dic but i get null values plz help me my code is as below

NOTE: ARRAY WHICH I AM USING FOR KEY, ALWAYS EXIST AS KEY IN DIC

```
NSDictionary *birthdayDictionary = 
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:_parssedArrayOfFaceBook forKeys:_parssedArrayOfFaceBookUid];

NSLog(@"asdas%@",birthdayDictionary.description);

NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *key in _selecteduid) {
    NSLog(@" see it%@",key);
    NSString *selectedBirthDate = [birthdayDictionary objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@" matched%@",selectedBirthDate);
    [matches addObject:selectedBirthDate];
    NSLog(@" matched%@",matches);

}
```

Comment: NSLog(@"asdas%@",birthdayDictionary.description); what this prints?

Comment: the Dic which i showed as sample Dic

Comment: pls giv sample what it prints

Comment: 100000297621293 = "08/31/1990";
100001904155266 = "12/30/1990";
100003248631105 = "05/27/1990";
100004327360299 = "01/01/1927";
100000157646688 = "08/22/1989";
100001069796883 = "12/03/1989";
100001475514001 = "03/09/1990";
100000717474427 = "08/05/1990";
100001221367192 = "08/05/1990";
100002586744158 = "04/15/1983";

Comment: it is so big thats why im showing just part of it

Comment: **dictionary with 2 array one for keys and one for values my dictionary look like this** creating confusion. what are two arrays and where are they in the output

Comment: They aren't arrays lol.

Comment: NSLog(@"asdas%@",birthdayDictionary); see what it givs and give sample eg

Comment: the ids that you see in sample Dic is made of one array and the birth dates that you see in Dic is made of another array

Comment: Try this one and telll the output, `for(NSString uid in _selecteduid){
  NSLog(@"%@ : %@", uid, birthDictionary[uid]);
}`

Comment: syntax erro array subscript is not an intiger

Comment: ok, use [birthDicionary objectForKey:uid]` Now tell the output

Comment: null thats the problem Anoop why getting null when i see in dic then there is key and value why not getting that value ?

Comment: if possible mail to me in my id, (i will check here), find id in my profile.

Comment: What is the object `_selecteduid`? Did you also try to initialize your `NSMutableArray`s?

Comment: Why is `*selectedBirthDate` an `NSMutableArray`? The birth dates (values) are strings! not arrays! use `NSString *selectedBirthDate = ...`.

Comment: Also could tell us what output does the following line inside the for loop gives: `NSLog(@" see it%@",key);`

Comment: You code looks file, except the NSMutableArray for selectedBirthDate. If you can log _selecteduid and see output, everything would work fine.

Comment: For `matches`, use `NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`. And inside the loop, try using `[matches addObject: [birthdayDictionary objectForKey:key]];` remove the intermediate array `selectedBirthDate`. I think it shouldn't be an array as suggested by @cdo anyway.

Comment: if i apply same logic in another project then its working but now in mine i dont know why. i also changed that mutable array to string but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is `*selectedBirthDate` an `NSMutableArray`? The birth dates (values) are strings! not arrays!

```
NSString *selectedBirthDate = [birthdayDictionary objectForKey:key];
```

Comment: i tried it too but not working so thats why i changed to to NSMutableArray to just check

Comment: same code is working in another project can it be the problem that in Dic the values for keys are in "","","", they are not in "" in another project and its working fine there but not here

Comment: Not a string eh? Try this to find out what kind of class that value really is... `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass[[birthdayDictionary objectForKey:key] class]);`

Comment: THERE ARE SOME NULL VALUES FOR KEYS IN DIC IS IT THE REASON FOR PROBLEM?

Comment: Yes, you cannot insert a NULL value into an NSMutableArray, it will cause a crash. Check for NULL before you call addObject.

Comment: there are some null values in Values of Dic as i have fatched birthdates from facebook, some friends have private birthdate how can i change array which having null value to simple nothing at that particular index lets say empty space like "  ". ?

Comment: Are the values actually NULL or are they strings that say "(null)"?

Comment: Dic contain NULL values for some keys i think i should do something to my Dic and change ALL NULL values to empty string but i dont know how to do it

Comment: that array is like this  "04/25/1990",
    "03/13",
    "01/01",
    "<null>",
    "12/15/1905",
    "07/10",
    "11/02/1990",
    "12/30/1990",
    "<null>",
    "07/22/1990",

Comment: you can see there is null values in it

Comment: try `if (selectedBirthDate == NULL) { selectedBirthDate = @""; }` ... that's assuming they are actually NULL. That will add empty strings instead of NULL to your matches array.

Comment: alternatively, "<null>" could be a string. so you might try `if ([selectedBirthDate isEqualToString:@"<null>"]) { selectedBirthDate = @""; }`

Comment: i did way you said i found that they are not NULL just string displaying  "<null>" but its not null.

Comment: everything is perfect dont know whats wrong. this same thing is working in another project

Comment: So if none of the values are null, but some of them say "<null>", just replace those ones with empty strings like I demonstrated. What further problem is there?

Comment: there is no difference between string saying "null" and empty string it should fetch value like "<null>" if key is for that particular value

Comment: but let me try as you said its good to do something then nothing

Comment: and string saying null is in values not in keys

Comment: I'm so completely confused now as to what your actual problem is anymore. Please be VERY VERY clear about what your actual problem is.

Comment: problem is same as i have asked question can i think problem is my ns dic keys are intiger and im searching them in NSString let me search them in intiger form or let me convert my NSDIC keys to string

Comment: You mean NSNumber, NSDictionaryKeys cannot be integer type.

Comment: i dont know man mind is running every single possibility to find solution

Comment: Also, Facebook User IDs are bigint(20) and will eventually be 64 bit. So to keep your app future-proof, Facebook IDs as strings would be safest.

Comment: thanks for everything man let me just search for it. if you find something then let me know. thank you so much

Comment: I think you should spend some time learning how to work with the fundamentals of Objective-C. Pick up some books and really learn how to use NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, NSNumber with solid competency. Your solution is not coming easily because you don't have a solid understanding of these objects. Also, you should spend some time writing very clean, very easy to read code so that it is easier for other people like myself to read and understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming selecteduid is a retained property and it has values in it, this code would work fine.

```
NSDictionary *birthdayDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:self.parssedArrayOfFaceBook
                                                                   forKeys:self.parssedArrayOfFaceBookUid];
    NSMutableArray *matches = [@[] mutableCopy];

    for (NSString *key in self.selecteduid){
        NSString *selectedBirthDate = birthdayDictionary[key];
        [matches addObject:selectedBirthDate];
    }
```